# D3 bubbles force layout animation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to build a simple D3 Bubble force layout and I'm following some examples and getting good results :) This is the current status:

**http://jsfiddle.net/2YhQR/1/**

```
    circle.on('mouseover', function() {
    d3.select(this).transition().attr('r', function(d) {
        return d.bigradius;
    });
});

circle.on('mouseout', function() {
    d3.select(this).transition().attr('r', function(d) {
        return d.radius;
    });
});
```

When you *mouseover* a bubble it gets bigger using a nice transition and I want the other bubbles to animate too to make room to the bigger bubble. But I do not know how to do that.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to re-run the force layout (in particular the collision function) with the updated radius, for example by calling the `tick` function when the transition is finished.

```
circle.on('mouseover', function() {
    d3.select(this).transition().attr('r', function(d) {
        d._radius = d.radius;
        d.radius = d.bigradius;
        return d.bigradius;
    }).each("end", function() { tick({alpha: 1e-6}); });
});
```

Proof of concept [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2YhQR/3/). It's not quite perfect -- there's some jumpiness initially. This could be improved with more suitable values for alpha...